# If $A \Rightarrow B$ then is it true that not $A \Rightarrow$ not $B$?

Tags: logic

If $A \Rightarrow B$ then is it true that not $A \Rightarrow$ not $B$?

I know that $A \Rightarrow B$ is equivalent to not $B\Rightarrow$ not $A$, but I am not sure about the first one.

Comment: Actually I asked this in haste, and have just come up with a counter example, suppose A is the statement: f is differentiable and B is the statement f is continous, then A implies B but not A does not imply not B.

Comment: I think you can post your own answer (though you won't be allowed to accept it for a short time)

Comment: If this is true then $A$ is actually equivalent to $B$

Comment: If A is logically equivalent to B, then this holds.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I asked this in haste, and have just come up with a counter example, suppose A is the statement: f is differentiable and B is the statement f is continuous, then A implies B but not A does not imply not B.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this counts as an answer on a website such as Math.SE (but Lewis Carroll *was* a mathematician)

Here's a quote from Alice's Adventures In Wonderland. You'll find that simple counter-examples in logic can be obtained by tweaking the false statements made here.

> 'Then you should say what you mean,' the March Hare went on.
>
> 'I do,' Alice hastily replied; 'at least--at least I mean what I say--that's the same thing, you know.'
>
> 'Not the same thing a bit!' said the Hatter. 'You might just as well say that "I see what I eat" is the same thing as "I eat what I see"!'
>
> 'You might just as well say,' added the March Hare, `that "I like what I get" is the same thing as "I get what I like"!'
>
> 'You might just as well say,' added the Dormouse, who seemed to be talking in his sleep, 'that "I breathe when I sleep" is the same thing as "I sleep when I breathe"!'

For instance, "I see what I eat" does not mean "I don't see what I don't eat". :)

Comment: "The best book on programming for the layman is Alice in Wonderland, but that's because it's the best book on anything for the layman." --Alan Perlis

Comment: This is great! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. Take a general and simplified example:

Suppose A is "in Washington" and B is "in USA". Then A $\implies$ B, definitely. But not A, say, "in San Francisco", does not necessarily imply not B.

Answer (score 0):

No it's false. example :
A : the figure is a square
B : the figure is a rectangle

you can say:  A⇒B

but you can't say:  not A⇒not B

Comment: $((A\implies B)\equiv(\lnot B\implies\lnot A))$    Check it with a truth table.

Answer (score 0):

No: $A\implies B$ is definite as $(\text{not}\,A)\,\text{or}\,B$, so that $\text{not}\,A\implies\text{not}\,B$ is $A\,\text{or}\,(\text{not}B)$ which is in general not equivalent to  $(\text{not} A)\,\text{or}\,B$.

For example, take "If a polygon is a square, then it is a rectangle" is $A\implies B$, so that "If a polygon is not a square, then it is not a rectangle" is $\text{not}\,A\implies\text{not}\,B$, which is obviously not true.